# Usando Ajax para atualizar um grafico em tempo real, sem da REFRESH

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-charts

Pessoal eu tive um duvida recentemente que era sobre como pegar dados do php para colocar no meu gráfico, agora eu quero fazer com que ele atualize em tempo real com o Ajax, quando eu inserir dados no meu banco de dados essa informação seja atualizada no meu gráfico, meu código esta assim :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testando dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
  

<?php
include "../cadastro/config.php";
        $quer_cont1 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result1 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont1);
        $result1->execute();
        $qntvez1 = array();
        $bairro1 = array();

        $i = 0;

        
         
          while($row_cont1 = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              $qntvez1 = $row_cont1['qntvez'];
              $bairro1 = $row_cont1['bairros'];
        };
        $quer_cont2 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 2";
        $result2 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont2);
        $result2->execute();
        $qntvez2 = array();
        $bairro2 = array();
        while($row_cont2 = $result2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $qntvez2 = $row_cont2['qntvez'];
          $bairro2 = $row_cont2['bairros'];
    };
    $quer_cont3 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 3";
        $result3 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont3);
        $result3->execute();
        $qntvez3 = array();
        $bairro3 = array();
        while($row_cont3 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $qntvez3 = $row_cont3['qntvez'];
          $bairro3 = $row_cont3['bairros'];
    };
    $quer_cont4 = "SELECT bairro AS bairros,COUNT(bairro) AS qntvez  FROM cadastro GROUP BY bairro HAVING COUNT(bairro) >= 1 ORDER BY count(bairro) DESC LIMIT 4";
    $result4 = $conn->prepare($quer_cont4);
    $result4->execute();
    $qntvez4 = array();
    $bairro4 = array();
    while($row_cont4 = $result4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $qntvez4 = $row_cont4['qntvez'];
      $bairro4 = $row_cont4['bairros'];
};
        
      
        ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var dados = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       

        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ['<?php echo $bairro1 ?>', <?php echo $qntvez1 ?>, "#b87333"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro2 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez2 ?>, "silver"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro3 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez3 ?>, "gold"],
        ["<?php echo $bairro4 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez4 ?>, "color: #e5e4e2"]
   
   
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dados);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       ]);

      var options = {
        title:  "Bairros que mais compram",
        width: 540,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
      
  }
  console.log("testando1")

  
 $('#botao').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../js/index.php",
        dataType: false
       
      } ).done (function (data) {
          console.log(data)
         
          
    })
  })
})
```

Eu ate consigo receber os dados com o console.log(data), só que esses dados não atualizam meu gráfico, quando faço determinada ação, Alguém por favor me da uma luz do que fazer...

Answer (score -3):

O negócio de atualizar os dados em "tempo real" via AJAX é que você vai ter que usar um `setOuttime` no teu código javascript, deixando o seu código assim:

```
        <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(() => { //Adicionei isso
        google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
          var dados = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           
    
            ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
            ['<?php echo $bairro1 ?>', <?php echo $qntvez1 ?>, "#b87333"],
            ["<?php echo $bairro2 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez2 ?>, "silver"],
            ["<?php echo $bairro3 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez3 ?>, "gold"],
            ["<?php echo $bairro4 ?>", <?php echo $qntvez4 ?>, "color: #e5e4e2"]
       
       
          ]);
    
          var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dados);
          view.setColumns([0, 1,
                           { calc: "stringify",
                             sourceColumn: 1,
                             type: "string",
                             role: "annotation" },
                           ]);
    
          var options = {
            title:  "Bairros que mais compram",
            width: 540,
            height: 400,
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            legend: { position: "none" },
          };
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
          chart.draw(view, options);
      }
      console.log("testando1")
    
     $('#botao').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../js/index.php",
            dataType: false
           
          } ).done (function (data) {
              console.log(data)
     
        });
      });
}, "1000"); //Adicionei isso: o 1000 representa o tempo em milissegundos que o seu código sofrerá um refresh automático. O que indica que esses 1000 é igual a 1 segundo, ou seja, a cada 1 segundo, o seu gráfico atualizará e receber novos dados do banco.
    });
```

## **Importante: **

Ao utilizar o método `setTimeout`, o seu código estará atualizando automaticamente a cada milissegundo que você definir para ele. E no que isso implica? Consumirá muito do seu servidor e também do MySql!

Imagina o que acontecerá se 100 (cem) usuários acessarem instantaneamente a sua página que contém esse gráfico com `setTimeout`! Vão ser 100 novas conexões por segundo ao seu banco de dados. Em uma hora (3.600 segundos x 100 conexões) serão 360.000 conexões!

Por isso, acredito que esta forma não seja a mais correta possível. Procure por **WebSockets** e veja se isso pode ajudá-lo!